# Helper for DropDownLists with extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

Is the following helper idiomatic ASP.NET MVC? All the built-in `DropDownListFor` helpers only accept `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. If the Model doesn't have this list, but an `IEnumerable<SomeEntity>`, avoiding this conversion in the Razor template seems to require some more of its helpers.

```
namespace CompanyName.ProjectName.PresentationLayer.Helpers
{
    // ...documentation omitted...
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TElem>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, string>> expression,
        IEnumerable<TElem> elements,
        Func<TElem, string> valueFunc,
        Func<TElem, string> textFunc
    )
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata =
            ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
            elements.Select(elem => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = valueFunc(elem),
                Text = textFunc(elem),
                Selected = elem.Equals(metadata.Model)
            });

        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor<TModel, string>(expression, items);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native MVC solution is to pass your collection into the `SelectList` class.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item, new SelectList(Model.MyList, "ValueProperty", "TextProperty"))
```

This would make your helper method unnecessary.

However, the downside to the native approach is that there is no compile-time safety on the Text/Value properties, so you may still want to have a helper method similar to what you've written for this added benefit.

---

The `DropDownListFor` methods handle which item is selected for you, so you don't need to concern yourself with populating the `Selected` property for your `SelectListItem`s.

Your extension method is not idiomatic to `DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>` because you're not using a generic type for the given property. You would at least want to keep TProperty as a generic type, and add a third generic type to your extension method for the collection type. This would change your method signature to `DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TElem>` and your second parameter to `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression`.

However, your approach has one major design issue: you lose out on all the overloads that exist for `DropDownListFor`. While you could reimplement all of them, it would be tackling the wrong problem.

You essentially want an elegant way to create a SelectList, so that's what your extension method should do. A Linq extension that works similarly to the `ToDictionary` extension method would look like the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> valueFunc, Func<T, string> textFunc)
{
    return source.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = valueFunc(x),
        Text = textFunc(x)
    });
}
```

Then you can use the native MVC `DropDownListFor` on any collection easily:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item, Model.MyList.ToSelectList(x => x.ValueProperty, x => x.TextProperty))
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item, Model.MyList.ToSelectList(x => x.ValueProperty, x => x.TextProperty), "Choose...", new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why TProperty is not generic. And yes, I did not like losing all the overloads. Thank you for the suggestion on building a SelectList helper instead, and for pointing out that `DropDownListFor` can infer what item is selected without my aid. This is pinpointing exactly what I want to abstract away from the Razor template.

Comment: Regarding the generic property: in your method, you use `Expression<Func<TModel, string>>`, which forces the model property to be a string. Changing it to `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` would make it work like the native MVC methods.